# in extjs form data stored in database with error data

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, extjs

*this is extjs javascript code*

```
        Ext.require([
            //'Ext.form.*',
            //'Ext.layout.container.Column',
            //'Ext.tab.Panel'
            '*'
        ]);

        Ext.onReady(function() {
            Ext.QuickTips.init();

            var bd = Ext.getBody();


            bd.createChild({tag: 'h2', html: 'Form 5 - ... and forms can contain TabPanel(s)'});

            var required = '<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold" data-qtip="Required">*</span>';

            var tab2 = Ext.widget({
                title: 'Inner Tabs',
                xtype: 'form',
                id: 'innerTabsForm',
                collapsible: true,
                bodyPadding: 5,
                width: 600,
                 url:'http://localhost/form/database.php',
                fieldDefaults: {
                    labelAlign: 'top',
                    msgTarget: 'side'
                },
                defaults: {
                    anchor: '100%'
                },

                items: [{
                    xtype: 'container',
                    layout:'hbox',
                    items:[{
                        xtype: 'container',
                        flex: 1,
                        border:false,
                        layout: 'anchor',
                        defaultType: 'textfield',
                        items: [{
                            fieldLabel: 'First Name',
                            afterLabelTextTpl: required,
                            allowBlank: false,
                            name: 'first',
                            anchor:'95%'
                        }, {
                            fieldLabel: 'Enquiry Date ',
                            name: 'Enquiry Date ',
                            xtype: 'datefield'
                }]
                    },{
                        xtype: 'container',
                        flex: 1,
                        layout: 'anchor',
                        defaultType: 'textfield',
                        items: [{
                            fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
                            afterLabelTextTpl: required,
                            allowBlank: false,
                            name: 'last',
                            anchor:'95%'
                        },{
                            fieldLabel: 'Email',
                            afterLabelTextTpl: required,
                            allowBlank: false,
                            name: 'email',
                            vtype:'email',
                            anchor:'95%'
                        }]
                    }]
                },{
                    xtype:'tabpanel',
                    plain:true,
                    activeTab: 0,
                    height:600,
                    defaults:{
                        bodyPadding: 10
                    },
                    items:[{
                        title:'Personal Details',
                        defaults: {
                            width: 230
                        },
                        defaultType: 'textfield',

                        items: [{
                        fieldLabel: 'Age',
                        name: 'age',
                        xtype: 'numberfield',
                        minValue: 0,
                        maxValue: 100
                        },{
                    xtype: 'fieldset',
                    flex: 1,
                    title: 'Gender',
                    defaultType: 'radio', // each item will be a radio button
                    layout: 'anchor',
                    defaults: {
                        anchor: '100%',
                        hideEmptyLabel: false
                    },
                    items: [ {
                        checked: true,
                        boxLabel: 'Male',
                        name: 'gender',
                        inputValue: 'male'
                    }, {
                        boxLabel: 'Female',
                        name: 'gender',
                        inputValue: 'female'
                    }]
                },{
                    xtype: 'fieldset',
                    flex: 1,
                    title: 'Marrital Status',
                    defaultType: 'radio', // each item will be a radio button
                    layout: 'anchor',
                    defaults: {
                        anchor: '100%',
                        hideEmptyLabel: false
                    },
                    items: [ {
                        checked: true,
                        boxLabel: 'Single',
                        name: 'mstatus',
                        inputValue: 'single'
                    }, {
                        boxLabel: 'Married',
                        name: 'mstatus',
                        inputValue: 'married'
                    }]
                },{
                            fieldLabel: 'Company',
                            name: 'company',
                            value: 'Ext JS'
                        }, {
                            fieldLabel: 'Email',
                            name: 'email',
                            vtype:'email'
                        }]
                    },{
                        title:'Phone Numbers',
                        defaults: {
                            width: 230
                        },
                        defaultType: 'textfield',

                        items: [{
                            fieldLabel: 'Home',
                            name: 'home',
                            value: '(888) 555-1212'
                        },{
                            fieldLabel: 'Business',
                            name: 'business'
                        },{
                            fieldLabel: 'Mobile',
                            name: 'mobile'
                        },{
                            fieldLabel: 'Fax',
                            name: 'fax'
                        }]
                    },{
                        cls: 'x-plain',
                        title: 'Rmarks',
                        layout: 'fit',
                        items: {
                            xtype: 'htmleditor',
                            name: 'bio2',
                            fieldLabel: 'Remarks'
                        }
                    }]
                }],

                buttons: [{
                    text: 'Save',          
                    handler: function () {
                        tab2.getForm().submit({
                         method: 'POST',
                        url: 'http://localhost/form/database.php',
                            waitMsg: 'Saving...',   
                            success: function () {     
                                Ext.MessageBox.alert ('Message','Data has been saved');
                                tab2.getForm().reset();
                            },
                          failure: function () {   
                                Ext.MessageBox.alert ('Message','Saving data failed');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },{
                    text: 'Cancel',
                    handler: function () {
                        tab2.getForm().reset();
                    }
                }]
            });

            tab2.render(document.body);
            //tab2.render('form');
        });
```

php code

```
    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        if (!$con)
        {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_select_db("stratageeks", $con);
        $q=mysql_query ("INSERT INTO data (name,lastname) VALUES ('".isset($_POST['first'])."','".isset($_POST['last'])."')");
         if ($q) {
         echo '{"success":"true"}';
        }
        else {
          echo '{"success":"false"}';
        }

    ?>
```

above code is my Extjs javascript code 
and below code is my database code for inserting to data in database from extjs form

but data stored in database 
**name:1
lastname:1**

form post data is 
**name:ravi
lastname:kumar**

Comment: correct data is not insert with this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this bit of code:

```
. isset($_POST['first']) . "','" . isset($_POST['last']) .
```

`isset()` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`, which when inserted to the database translates to `1` and `0` respectively.

You may want to consider replacing your code with this:

```
$iFirst = isset( $_POST['first'] ) ? $_POST['first'] : '';
$iLast  = isset( $_POST['last'] )  ? $_POST['last']  : '';

$q = mysql_query ( "INSERT INTO data ( name, lastname ) VALUES ('". $iFirst ."','". $iLast ."')" );
```

And if it would be my code, it would look like this (notice the consistency in field/parameters names, which also makes refactoring easier):

```
$iFirstName = isset( $_POST['aFirstName'] ) ? $_POST['aFirstName'] : '';
$iLastName  = isset( $_POST['aLastName'] )  ? $_POST['aLastName']  : '';

$q = mysql_query ( "INSERT INTO data ( firstName, lastName ) VALUES ('". $iFirstName ."','". $iLastName ."')" );
```